# how to get only grandchild category from a child category

Tags: categories

how to get only grandchild  category from a child category list currently i am using the code bellow for get child category of parent.

```
<?php

$args = array(
'orderby' => 'name',
'parent' => 72,
'taxonomy' => 'category',
'hide_empty' => 0 ,
'number' => '21'
);
$categories =  get_categories('hide_empty=0&child_of='.$cat);
$content='';

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
echo '<div class="col-md-4 inline-block padding-0" style="margin-bottom:10px;"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">'.    $category->name . '</a></div>';

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to make another get_categories inside the foreach ( $categories as $category )

**Example code**

```
   //preparing an array to hold later info
    $grandchildren_ids = [];
    //getting the child categories of parent 72
    $args = array(
     'orderby' => 'name',
     'parent' => 72,
     'taxonomy' => 'category',
     'hide_empty' => 0
    );
    $categories =  get_categories($args);

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    //setting up the args where the parents are the child categories
     $grandchildrenargs=array(
     'parent' => $category->term_id,
     'taxonomy' => 'category',
     'hide_empty' => 0
     );
     $grandchildrencategories =  get_categories($grandchildrenargs);

      foreach ( $grandchildrencategories as $grandchildrencategory ) {
       //getting the grandchildren ids or whatever else is needed and populating the array
       $grandchildren_ids[] = $grandchildrencategory->term_id;
      }

     }
    var_dump($grandchildren_ids);
```